# Suggestions for making a Jeopardy game?

Tags: beamer

I've been looking to make Jeopardy-type games in LaTeX.  After some googling and tinkering, I haven't found anything satisfactory (I've looked into these links: [Jeopardy Review](https://www.math.psu.edu/ballif/twt/jeopardy.html), [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/jeopardy), [AcroTeX](http://www.acrotex.net/games_index.php?lang=en), and [this one here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91072/hide-button-after-its-selected-in-beamer)).

I'm not good enough with TeX to do this myself, and it seems such thing is out there somewhere, but I can't find it.  I've found tons of decent Jeopardy games, but nothing which take math code (for example, BYOJeopardy is great for Jeopardy but bad for math, whereas the  other things I linked are great for math but not good for Jeopardy).  I suspect this would be done with beamer (which I have plenty of experience with).

Edit for clarity: I am looking for some way (maybe a new document class?) which would allow me to make Jeopardy-type games.

To my knowledge, [this](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/jeopardy/example/game1-two.pdf) is the sort of thing you get from the jeopardy.sty found in the second link above, and I don't see how that's much like Jeopardy.

Comment: A snarky game host is included?

Comment: The game host can be snarky at times.

Comment: Given that you don't say why e.g. `jeopardy.sty` is unsatisfactory, I'm not really sure what you are asking. (That seems to be designed both for the jeopardy bit and the maths bit and so to fulfil both desiderata.)

Comment: So a satisfying solution would be to recreate the BYOjeopardy layout in beamer, right?

Comment: Yes, that would be a satisfying solution.  I'll make an edit for clarity.

Edit: Unless maybe I'm just not getting the second link in the original post to work correctly.  I am getting error messages, and the output doesn't look like Jeopardy at all.

Comment: What is BYOJeopardy? Or what does it look like? If you say that `jeopardy.sty` doesn't produce something which looks like Jeopardy, I believe you. I wouldn't know. However, it would be nice to know what something which did look like Jeopardy would look like ;).

Comment: It can make things like the image here: http://www.wolfescience.com/

It's not super fancy by any means, but gets the job done.  Problem is... typing math in there is a nightmare.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, here is some code that recreates the BYOjeopardy layout in Beamer to help you get started.

### Gif mockup

[image]

### The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamersize{text margin left=0cm, text margin right=0cm}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{ocgx}


\newtcolorbox{InnerSubjectBox}{
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    arc=0pt,
    width=.2\paperwidth,
    boxrule=.4pt,
    colframe=white,
    center upper,
    interior style={
        top color=blue,
        bottom color=black
    },
    colupper=white,
}

\newcommand{\subjects}[5]{×
    \begin{InnerSubjectBox}
        #1
    \end{InnerSubjectBox}%
    \begin{InnerSubjectBox}
        #2
    \end{InnerSubjectBox}%
    \begin{InnerSubjectBox}
        #3
    \end{InnerSubjectBox}%
    \begin{InnerSubjectBox}
        #4
    \end{InnerSubjectBox}%
    \begin{InnerSubjectBox}
        #5
    \end{InnerSubjectBox}
}

\newtcolorbox{InnerPrizeBox}{
    enhanced,
    nobeforeafter,
    arc=0pt,
    width=.2\paperwidth,
    boxrule=.4pt,
    colframe=white,
    center upper,
    interior style={
        top color=blue,
        bottom color=black
    },
    colupper=white,
    valign=center,
    fontupper=\LARGE\bfseries,
    height=.176\paperheight
}

\newcommand{\prizes}{%
    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}{%
        \begin{InnerPrizeBox}%
            \begin{ocg}{s\i-100}{s\i-100}{1}{\hyperlink{s\i-100}{100}}\end{ocg}
        \end{InnerPrizeBox}%
        }%

    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}{%
        \begin{InnerPrizeBox}%
            \begin{ocg}{s\i-200}{s\i-200}{1}{\hyperlink{s\i-200}{200}}\end{ocg}
        \end{InnerPrizeBox}%
        }%

    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}{%
        \begin{InnerPrizeBox}%
            \begin{ocg}{s\i-300}{s\i-300}{1}{\hyperlink{s\i-300}{300}}\end{ocg}
        \end{InnerPrizeBox}%
        }%

    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}{%
        \begin{InnerPrizeBox}%
            \begin{ocg}{s\i-400}{s\i-400}{1}{\hyperlink{s\i-400}{400}}\end{ocg}
        \end{InnerPrizeBox}%
        }%

    \foreach \i in {1,2,...,5}{%
        \begin{InnerPrizeBox}%
            \begin{ocg}{s\i-500}{s\i-500}{1}{\hyperlink{s\i-500}{500}}\end{ocg}
        \end{InnerPrizeBox}%
        }%
    }

\newtcolorbox{QuestionHeadFoot}[1][]{
    enhanced,
    before=\vskip-.7ex,
    after=,
    arc=0pt,
    width=\paperwidth,
    boxrule=.4pt,
    colframe=white,
    center upper,
    center lower,
    interior style={
        top color=blue,
        bottom color=black
    },
    colupper=white,
    collower=white,
    valign=center,
    fontupper=\LARGE\bfseries,
    fontlower=\LARGE\bfseries,
    height=.176\paperheight,
    sidebyside,
    segmentation style={white,solid,line width=.4pt},
    #1
}

\newcommand{\header}[2]{
    \begin{QuestionHeadFoot}
        Subject #1 \tcblower #2
    \end{QuestionHeadFoot}
}

\newcommand{\footer}[1]{
    \begin{QuestionHeadFoot}[before=\vskip-2.7ex]
        \hyperlink{question#1}{Question} \\ \hyperlink{answer#1}{Answer} \tcblower
        \hideocg{#1}{Done!} \\ \hyperlink{home}{Home}
    \end{QuestionHeadFoot}
}

\newcommand{\content}[4]{
\begin{frame}
    \hypertarget<1>{answer#1}{}
    \hypertarget<2>{question#1}{}
    \hypertarget{#1}{}
    \header{#2}{#3}
  #4
    \footer{#1}
\end{frame}
}

\newtcolorbox{textarea}[1][]{
    nobeforeafter,
    height=6.2cm,
    boxrule=0pt,
    center upper,
    valign=center,
    #1
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\hypertarget{home}{}
\vspace*{-.5cm}
    \subjects{Subject 1}{Subject 2}{Subject 3}{Subject 4}{Subject 5}
    \prizes
\end{frame}

\content                       % 4 arguments
    {s1-100}                     % question internal identifier
    {1}                          % subject number
    {100}{                       % question prize
        \begin{textarea}[]         % question/answer content
        \only<1>{                  % answer content
            $4$
        }
        \only<2>{                  % question content
            How much is $2+2$ ?
        }
        \end{textarea}
    }
\end{document}
```

I'm not going to explain everything step by step, but it should be clear that I used the `tcolorbox` package for the blocks (much more flexible than the standard beamer blocks) and the `ocgx` package for implementing and "disappearing" effect for already visited questions.

This code is fully automatic, what you need to do is to fill it with the actual content. The correct links from/to questions are already there. Each question/answer will be included in a `\content` macro like this:

```
\content                       % 4 arguments
    {s1-100}                     % question internal identifier
    {1}                          % subject number
    {100}{                       % question prize
        \begin{textarea}[]         % question/answer content
        \only<1>{                  % answer content
            $4$
        }
        \only<2>{                  % question content
            How much is $2+2$ ?
        }
        \end{textarea}
}
```

which should be self-explanatory. By default I centered the question/answer content both vertically and horizontally, but it can be easily changed customizing the `textarea` environment.

After the user checks the answer by clicking "Answer", he must click "Done!" (to activate the `ocg` that hides the prize from the home page) and then "Home" to go back to the home page, which will have one less prize.

The entire preambleshould be placed in a `.sty` file or whatever so that the actual `.tex` files consists only of a "home" frame plus 25 `\content` macros.

### Limitations

- As already noted in
  [Hide button after it's selected in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91072/hide-button-after-its-selected-in-beamer)
  Keyboard navigation breaks the entire game. This can be workarounded
  by employing a snarky host.
- Since it uses the `ocgx` package **this only works in Acrobat
  reader/pro/whatever**. It is possible to remove the `ocgx` dependecy but then there is no simple way to hide already visited questions.
- Unfortunately it seems there's no way to have a single button for both hiding the prize and going home.
- This is not perfect by any means and should be more thoroughly tested.
- I don't like this "jeopardy" game nor the BYOjeopardy layout ;)

Comment: Just an addendum: note that without leaning on something like ocgx/JavaScript/etc., you would have to generate pages for every possible path down the game tree.  That means a game board for every configuration and a set of question pages for each game board (since the links would change).  This blows up very, *very*, quickly.  Exponential time/space, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @SeanAllred true story: at a certain point I was actually going to try that, but gave up very quickly :)

Comment: Sorry, you didn't pose your answer in the form of a question.

Comment: @AlanMunn what do you mean? Do you mean my answer is more suited to be a question?

Comment: I guess you've never actually watched the show. :) The form of the game is that the clues are answers to questions, and the only valid way to get the points in the game is to pose your response in the form of a question.

Comment: @AlanMunn wow, I had completely overlooked that! Yes, I never watched the show, I'll fix the code to show the answers first. Thanks :)

Comment: @dcmst I actually wasn't criticizing the answer, just making a joke about its form.

Comment: yeah, sure, no problem. I couldn't get it at first because I didn't know how the game is actually meant to be played.

Comment: This is great!  Thank you very much, dcmst.  I did run into a problem, however.  I compiled it, automatically viewed it in Sumatra, the "Done!" button didn't work (which you know), so opened it in Adobe Reader XI instead, but even then the "Done!" button didn't make the 100-pointer disappear from the main board.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @danzibr I tried with acrobat reader 9 and XI, it works, you only need to compile it two or three times in a row. When you click "Done" you should see a yellow flash around the text. I've also uploaded a working pdf compiled by me for you to test: [dropbox link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cq67s6by23e6hfu/jeopardy.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: It works!  I guess I just didn't compile it enough times.  Thanks so much for doing this.  If, in a year's time, you want a few dozen Jeopardy-type games (though you admitted to not being the biggest fan) for math review through Calculus, just let me know ;)

Comment: @danzibr Actually I had not fully grasped the mechanics of the game, but now that I have (thanks to AlanMunn) I like it a bit more :o)

Comment: @danzibr have you actually made those games? I'd be interested in seeing them!